# C++ matrix crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Please, can someone tell me why after compiling the following code I get this error.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("graf2.txt", std::ios::in);         // Input file...

    std::list<int> lst;                                     // For a Grapf constructor usage...

    double mtx[MAX][MAX] = {0};                             // For a Grapf consturctor usage...

    
    if (!input.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "There was a problem opening the input file!\n";
        exit(1);                                                            //exit or do additional error checking
        
    }
    else
    {
        double debths;

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        int check = 0;

        while (input >> debths)
        {
            if (!check)
                check = (int)debths;
            else
                mtx[i++][j++] = debths;
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

error:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF731C7CD0A in SPA_round2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000BD153000C0.

MAX is defined as 100. In my input file I have an 13x13 matrix.

Comment: You probably have an array overrun. You're also only filling the diagonal of your matrix.

Comment: `mtx[i++][j++] = debths;` so you're writting to `mtx[0][0]`, then `mtx[1][1]`, then `mtx[2][2]`... What about , then `mtx[0][1]` and such?

Comment: Yes Sir and thank you. While loop needs to be replaced...Now my eyes are open.
Thanx for the help.

Comment: whats inside `"graf2.txt"`

Comment: First line containts the number of nodes.
Than the Matrix.
'graf2.txt' , 'graf' is the Serbian spell for the 'Graph' .

Answer (score 1):

13 x 13 matrix has 169 element then `input >> debths` is called 169 times. Meanwhile your `i` and `j` have max value of 100 cause access violation at `mtx[i++][j++]` when `i` or `j` > 100.